# How to validate firebase MessagingPayload size

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

How can I validate title and message of MessaginPayload.

I have nodejs function to send notification message to my mobile app.

Sometime we got error, because message is exceed the limit.

Firebase mention that Notification messages can contain an optional data payload. Maximum payload for both message types is 4000 bytes, except when sending messages from the Firebase console, which enforces a 1024 character limit.

So how can I check the message payload in nodejs.

```
import * as firebaseAdmin from "firebase-admin";
import serviceAccount from "./service-account-file.json";

const admin = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp(
  {
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount as 
firebaseAdmin.ServiceAccount),
  },
  "server"
);

const fcm = admin.messaging();

 const sendMessage = async (title: any, message: any) => {
  var topic = "mydomain.org";
  const payload: firebaseAdmin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
    notification: {
      title: title,
      body: message,
      click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", // required only for onResume or 
onLaunch callbacks
    },
  };

  return await fcm.sendToTopic(topic, payload);
};

 export { sendMessage };
```